# How to combine the following queries result in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

FIRST QUERY

```
    select b.id , b.value,b.name from table_1 b where b.id = 900;
```

RESULT:

```
  id     value    name
 900     5027      AA
 900     79426     BB   
 900     132276    CC
 900     302885    DD
```

SECOND QUERY

```
select a.id , max(a.value) from table_1 a where a.id = 900 group by a.id ;
```

RESULT

```
 id     value
900     302885
```

Now i want the result like

```
  id      value   name
  900     302885    DD
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t
WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table_1 s WHERE t.id = s.id)
AND t.id = 900
```

Other examples of how to do it can be found in the manual entry [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ce97/1/0).

Comment: this query is giving all the columns for me

Comment: @PSR Sure no copy&paste error? Tried it with an sqlfiddle (see updated answer). Works perfectly for me and I can see no error in this.

Answer (score 1):

use your first query but in the where clause select the value which you want... this can be done by using a select MAX() statement

```
select b.id , b.value,b.name 
from table_1 b 
where b.id = 900 and 
b.value = (
    select max(a.value) from table_1 a where a.id = 900 group by a.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
select * 
from Table1 t1 
where t1.value=(select MAX(value) 
                from Table1 t2 
                where t1.id=t2.id) 
AND t1.id=900;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8094/4)